# Ajax sometimes wont return even there is an output

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know I'm gonna get a lot of negative points, but cannot describe this better.

There is an url: `localhost/mycall.php`

The PHP code at this endpoint sleeps a random number of seconds then returns JSON data.

If I call this endpoint directly on via the browser it always works, however if I try to call it via AJAX in a `document.ready` call like below.

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/mycall.php?' + new Date().getTime() + Math.random(1, 99999),
    data: dataToSend,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('success');
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('error');
        console.log(textStatus);
    },
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log('complete');
        console.log(textStatus);
    }
});
```

It returns after a while but with no data and none of the callbacks are fired.
This happens in Opera, Chrome, even in the newest Firefox. Why would this be the case?

I forget to mention, output has "Content-Type":"text/plain; charset=utf-8" headers, mightbe this is the problem... ?

Comment: We need to see the PHP code

Comment: Javascript does not allow you to make ajax requests to a different host than the one from which the current page was obtained from. Is the page containing the Javascript on the same domain as the PHP or is it just a local file?

Comment: And you're not getting a same-origin warning in the console ?

Comment: if you put domain in url must also use at least `//` before it or put full protocol. Inspect actual request in browser dev tools network and you will see url is incorrect as well as status

Comment: @adeneo no Im not

Answer (score 1):

It seems there's problem with your `url` , maybe you should not write `localhost`?

Answer (score 1):

This same thing often happens with me. But when I see this problem,if I define data formate then check coming response is in correct json formate.
Then after encoding json correctly. problem solves.
I don't know what actually happening with you.May be this would be helpful for you.

Comment: I forget to mention, output has "Content-Type":"text\/plain; charset=utf-8" headers, mightbe this is the problem... ?

Answer (score 1):

You should prefix your url with `/`. Without it it will be treated as a relative path.

Comment: of course I use this and with relative path (/mycall.php)